# I couldn't start my JBoss EAP 7 service

Tags: jboss

I installed JBoss EAP-7.1.0 through windows installer and then configured it as a service. But now I couldn't start the service, i tried through the windows task manager but it shows Access denied. (see the screenshot below)

[image]

How to start the service with admin privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:

1. Launch Command prompt as Administrator
2. Type in `sc start JBossEAP7`